# Android print framework - Silent print custom pdf to predetermined printer

Tags: java, android, pdf, printing, bluetooth

I am developing a POS application for android.
What i need to do is print the bill when you click on a button.
The print needs to happen silently to a predetermined printer without any interaction with the app. The printer will be found with its IP address set up in code.
The connection should happen true wifi or bluetooth (probably wifi).

What i have tried so far is use the android print framework (In Android 4.4 (API level 19) ), but it seems to be stuck to the gui (Again i dont want any gui for the print, it just needs to happen). I couldn't find the option to set the printer IP true code.

I have followed a simple tutorial to create the code that i have right now.
Here is a link to it:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Custom_Document_Printing_Tutorial

So to recap, i need my custom Android POS app to print bills(or just anything for starters) to a predetermined printer that i set up in code.

It seems that Rongta pos printers has a android sdk.
I guess other manufacturers have to have one as well for their printers.

Comment: Android's print framework is designed for use in conventional Android scenarios. There, the user needs the UI, for confirmation and configuration of the print job. I know of no way to bypass that. It is possible that, in the future, Android Things will allow for a direct-printing option, and it's possible that makes its way into base Android, but AFAIK that is not there now.

Your more likely course of action will be to talk to the printer manufacturer and get the details of how to talk to the printer directly (e.g., direct socket connection) and roll your own printing system.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.

Comment: Any clue how they managed to make this work?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_inOqDzqjg This is a link of a croatian video where they show off their POS app that does exactly what i want, they are compatible with quite a few printers.

Comment: Presumably, they talked to the manufacturers of those printers. I would assume that there are a few relevant standards or specifications for data connection, printer commands, and sending data. So, once you have a couple of printers implemented "the hard way", others become mostly a matter of testing. In addition, there might be existing libraries for direct-printing to classes of printers, bypassing the print framework.

Comment: Okey thanks, I managed to find the documentation for Rongta pos printers and they seem to have a android sdk. So i guess that's how i do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot silent print the document in Android. There is an open issue on AOSP issue tracker.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160908.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for printint to PDF by calling print adapter lifecycle methods. However as callbacks are non public abstract classes and system throws segfault if null is supplied, you need to use [DexMaker](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker) to implement them. I have implemented for webView adapter like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    File file = new File(pdfPath);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        file.createNewFile();

        // get file descriptor
        descriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);

        // create print attributes
        PrintAttributes attributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
                .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
                .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("id", PRINT_SERVICE, 300, 300))
                .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
                .setMinMargins(new PrintAttributes.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0))
                .build();
        ranges = new PageRange[]{new PageRange(1, numberPages)};

        // dexmaker cache folder
        cacheFolder =  new File(context.getFilesDir() +"/etemp/");

        printAdapter.onStart();

        printAdapter.onLayout(attributes, attributes, new CancellationSignal(), getLayoutResultCallback(new InvocationHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object o, Method method, Object[] objects) throws Throwable {

                if (method.getName().equals("onLayoutFinished")) {
                    onLayoutSuccess();
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Layout failed");
                    pdfCallback.onPdfFailed();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }, cacheFolder), new Bundle());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, e != null ? e.getMessage() : "PrintPdfTask unknown error");
    }
    return null;
}

private void onLayoutSuccess() throws IOException {
    PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback callback = getWriteResultCallback(new InvocationHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object o, Method method, Object[] objects) throws Throwable {
            if (method.getName().equals("onWriteFinished")) {
                pdfCallback.onPdfCreated();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Layout failed");
                pdfCallback.onPdfFailed();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }, cacheFolder);
    printAdapter.onWrite(ranges, descriptor, new CancellationSignal(), callback);
}


/**
 * Implementation of non public abstract class LayoutResultCallback obtained via DexMaker
 * @param invocationHandler
 * @param dexCacheDir
 * @return LayoutResultCallback
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback getLayoutResultCallback(InvocationHandler invocationHandler,
                                                                                File dexCacheDir) throws IOException {
    return ProxyBuilder.forClass(PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback.class)
            .dexCache(dexCacheDir)
            .handler(invocationHandler)
            .build();
}

/**
 * Implementation of non public abstract class WriteResultCallback obtained via DexMaker
 * @param invocationHandler
 * @param dexCacheDir
 * @return LayoutResultCallback
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback getWriteResultCallback(InvocationHandler invocationHandler,
                                                                              File dexCacheDir) throws IOException {
    return ProxyBuilder.forClass(PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback.class)
            .dexCache(dexCacheDir)
            .handler(invocationHandler)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.